# Lumen error illuminate/support/Arr.php on line 145

Tags: php, laravel-5, lumen-5.2

In my local development environment its works fine, but when i deploy the `lumen(5.2)` project in server and 
when it's try to execute this line `app('db')->select($sql, array($email));` then it's throw this exception

```
protected 'message' => string 'array_key_exists(): The first argument  should be either a string or an integer' (length=78)
private 'string' (Exception) => string '' (length=0)
protected 'code' => int 0
protected 'file' => string 
'/usr/src/app/api/vendor/illuminate/support/Arr.php' (length=50)
protected 'line' => int 145
private 'trace' (Exception) => 
array (size=32)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'function' => string 'Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}' (length=32)
      'class' => string 'Laravel\Lumen\Application' (length=25)
      'type' => string '->' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array (size=5)
          ...
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'file' => string '/usr/src/app/api/vendor/illuminate/support/Arr.php' (length=50)
      'line' => int 145
      'function' => string 'array_key_exists' (length=16)
      'args' => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
  2 => 
    array (size=6)
      'file' => string '/usr/src/app/api/vendor/illuminate/support/Arr.php' (length=50)
      'line' => int 280
      'function' => string 'exists' (length=6)
      'class' => string 'Illuminate\Support\Arr' (length=22)
      'type' => string '::' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
  3 => 
    array (size=6)
      'file' => string '/usr/src/app/api/vendor/illuminate/database/DatabaseManager.php' (length=63)
      'line' => int 238
      'function' => string 'get' (length=3)
      'class' => string 'Illuminate\Support\Arr' (length=22)
      'type' => string '::' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
  4 => 
    array (size=6)
      'file' => string '/usr/src/app/api/vendor/illuminate/database/DatabaseManager.php' (length=63)
      'line' => int 158
      'function' => string 'getConfig' (length=9)
      'class' => string 'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager' (length=35)
      'type' => string '->' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
  5 => 
    array (size=6)
      'file' => string '/usr/src/app/api/vendor/illuminate/database/DatabaseManager.php' (length=63)
      'line' => int 68
      'function' => string 'makeConnection' (length=14)
      'class' => string 'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager' (length=35)
      'type' => string '->' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
  6 => 
    array (size=6)
      'file' => string '/usr/src/app/api/vendor/illuminate/database/DatabaseManager.php' (length=63)
      'line' => int 317
      'function' => string 'connection' (length=10)
      'class' => string 'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager' (length=35)
      'type' => string '->' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
```

I think its happen for set up environment in server , Please suggest me what i have to do..

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable error logging on your development machine?

Share your code which one is you're using with `array_key_exists` function.

Also share your current php version of development & server machine.

Comment: development `php 7.0.8` & server machine `PHP >= 5.6.4`

Comment: I not enable error logging on my development machine

Comment: If you don't enable or could not see the error while developing then how you solve or how you figured out from where the error is coming?

Please check the log file.
There maybe `array_key_exists` function got null param instead of array.
And make sure you've the latest version of lumen.

Comment: Thank's @Sohel Amin, the problem was in my database connection.

Comment: in my .env file the DB_CONNECTION field was set default "true" by Docker where as it should be postgresql deriver name "pgsql".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem right now. I've received an error max_memory_limit, but because of nothing. In that case WAMP/LAMP/XAMP restart should help. Mye be helpful for somebody... :)

Answer (score 0):

please enable  `$app->withEloquent();` in `bootstrap/app.php`. If you are using db, you must do this.